# Unable to match alphanumeric string with wildcard inside query_string in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I'm using the following mapping:

```
"letters": {
    "mappings": {
       "letter": {
          "properties": {
            "destCode": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "tag": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My docs contains two fields:

- tag: mostly alphanumeric and may contain some '/' or '@'chars
- destCode: 99% a numeric string

The following query_String (i know wildcards are bad):

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "destCode",
        "query": "*604"
    }   
}
```

correctly matches 0144604, 4521604 destCode values.

But it doesn't work for tag field, for ex the query:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "tag",
        "query": "CDG*" 
    }   
}
```

does not match values: CDG711892, CDG88978 and i also tried lowercase cdg* without success.

Comment: @mfundi Can you provide us with some sample documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mapping you set the field as not analyzed, because of that when you index data, elasticsearch don't analyzed it,because of that if you index data as lowercase you will not hit nothing if you search uppercase.
Remove

```
index": "not_analyzed
```

And it will work